# Promise wont return valid value

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have this test I made just to check an API, but then i tryied to add an URL from a second fetch using as parameter a value obtained in the first fetch and then return a value to add in the first fecth. The idea is to add the image URL to the link. thanks in advance.

```
function script() {
    const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20'

    const result = fetch(url)
    .then( (res)=>{
        if(res.ok) {
            return res.json()
        } else {
            console.log("Error!!")
        }
    }).then( data => {
        console.log(data)

        const main = document.getElementById('main');

        main.innerHTML=`<p><a href='${data.next}'>Next</a></p>`;

        for(let i=0; i<data.results.length;i++){
            main.innerHTML=main.innerHTML+`<p><a href=${getImageURL(data.results[i].url)}>${data.results[i].name}</a></p>`;
        }

    })
}

 async function getImageURL(imgUrl) {
   
    const resultImg = await fetch(imgUrl)
        .then( (res)=> {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then (data => {
            console.log(data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default);            
        })    
    return resultImg.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, don't mix `.then`/`.catch` handlers with `async`/`await`. There's usually no need, and it can trip you up like this.

The problem is that your fulfillment handler (the `.then` callback) doesn't return anything, so the promise it creates is fulfilled with `undefined`.

You could return `data`, but really just don't use `.then`/`.catch` at all:

```
async function getImageURL(imgUrl) {
    const res = await fetch(imgUrl);
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
    }
    const resultImg = await res.json();
    return resultImg.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default;
}
```

[Note I added a check of `res.ok`. This is (IMHO) a footgun in the `fetch` API, it doesn't reject its promise on HTTP errors (like 404 or 500), only on *network* errors. You have to check explicitly for HTTP errors. (I wrote it up on my anemic old blog [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).)]

There's also a problem where you *use* `getImageURL`:

```
// Incorrent
for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    main.innerHTML=main.innerHTML+`<p><a href=${getImageURL(data.results[i].url)}>${data.results[i].name}</a></p>`;
}
```

The problen here is that `getImageURL`, like all `async` functions, returns a *promise*. You're trying to use it as those it returned the fulfillment value you're expecting, but it can't — it doesn't have that value yet.

Instead, you need to wait for the promise(s) youre creating in that loop to be fulfilled. Since that loop is in synchronous code (not an `async` function), we'd go back to `.then`/`.catch`, and since we want to wait for a group of things to finish that can be done in parallel, we'd do that with `Promise.all`:

```
// ...
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const html = `<p><a href='${data.next}'>Next</a></p>`;
Promise.all(data.results.map(async ({url, name}) => {
    const realUrl = await getImageURL(url);
    return `<p><a href=${realUrl}>${name}</a></p>`;
}))
.then(paragraphs => {
    html += paragraphs.join("");
    main.innerHTML = html;
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For one, your

```
.then (data => {
            console.log(//...
```

at the end of the promise chain returns undefined. Just remove it, and if you want to `console.log` it, do `console.log(resultImg)` in the next statement/next line, after `await`.

Answer (score 0):

This the final version that accomplish my goal. Just want to leave this just in case someone finds it usefull. Thanks for those who answer!

```
function script() {
    const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20'

    const result = fetch(url)
    .then( (res)=>{
        if(res.ok) {
            return res.json()
        } else {
            console.log("Error!!")
        }
    }).then( data => {
        console.log(data)

        const main = document.getElementById('main');

        main.innerHTML=`<p><a href='${data.next}'>Proxima Página</a></p>`;

        Promise.all(data.results.map(async ({url, name}) => {
            const realUrl = await getImageURL(url);
            return `<div><a href=${realUrl}>${name}</a></div>`;
        }))
        .then(paragraphs => {
            main.innerHTML=main.innerHTML+paragraphs;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })
}

 async function getImageURL(imgUrl) {
   
    const res = await fetch(imgUrl);

    if(!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error ${res.status}`)
    } 
    
    const resultImg = await res.json();

    return resultImg.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default
}
```